# MySQL Workbench / Forward Engineering Progress - Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So i have a little problem while learning MySQL/PHP.
I have installed XAMPP and the MySQL Workbench, in order to learn (play around) some basic SQL/PHP stuff.

My XAMPP shows that my SQL server is up and running (it clearly says MySQL), but nonetheless, i get an error, each time i try to implement a schema on my sql-server.

As for now, i have only used the EER/Forward Engineering method of implementing a database with the MySQL-Workbench. Each time i try to complete the process after modelling the EER model, i get errors like this:

***Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')***

Does anyone here have an idea how to fix this?

Greetings.

Comment: Can you show us also the generated SQL? You probably forgot to specify something in your model.

Answer (score 0):

[Thats what the generated SQL looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO6Ih.jpg)

I also tried setting the "Target SQL Version" in the Model preferences to 5.6, as well as overall preferences.

As a little desperation move, i deinstalled XAMPP and the MySQL Workbench, and installed the newest versions - XAMPP (7.3.8 , using MariaDB) and the Workbench (8.0.17)

What am i missing?

Comment: There are several foreign keys defined, but not completely filled. The columns in your table and target table are not selected. For example `FOREIN KEY () REFERENCES mytunes.Plattenfirma ()`. This is the syntax: `CONSTRAINT constraint_name
FOREIGN KEY foreign_key_name (columns)
REFERENCES parent_table(columns)
ON DELETE action
ON UPDATE action`